# Flash Player hangs few seconds after NetStream.publish() on Mac Only

Tags: flash, apache-flex, live, netstream, netconnection

I'm having a realy wierd issue since the last two days.
I'm developping a Flex Application to be able to live stream video.
Every thing works just fine on Windows but on MacOs the NetStream Stops streaming after a few seconds (3 to 10 seconds) but it doesn't fire any event or Error. It Just simply stops publishing. My video LoopBack continues to show the live capture but the remote player show a freezed image. The remote player application simply gets "NetStream.Buffer.Empty" since the emitter stops publishing.

The weird thing is there is no Error on the server log (Red5) the only I get is a WARN Message

> WARN  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPTConnection
>   from 127.0.0.1 : 57550 to localhost (in: 68623 out 3429 ), with id
>   1433242212, due to too much inactivity (65000ms), last ping sent
>   5000ms ago

But when I try to shutdown the Publisher application it hangs the FlashPlayer, so I have to kill the process in the Activity monitor.

This bug is driving me nuts since 2 days. Could anyone help me get through this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS: My NetStream and NetConnetion object are public class variable so it shouldn't be the Garbage Collector.

Comment: What happens if you lower the framerate or quality? Is there a level that the client will tolerate?

Comment: I lowered the Framerate to 10 fps and the quality to 50%. I still get the Netsteam stopping the publishing. If you any other suggestion I am all ears! Thanks btw

Comment: Do the red5 samples work on the mac?

Comment: I just tried publishig with the red5 publisher App and I got the same behavior: Application hangs after a few seconds and make the browser hang as well ...

Comment: I had the same behavior on two MacBook Pro. Both of them run on MacOs X Lion

Comment: Lion has other issues too. Try a diff version. Red5 has been pretty well tested. Im suspicious of the browser in this case.

Comment: I also don't think that the problem comes from Red5 since it perfectly works on Windows. I also suspected the browser at first but I tried on Firefox, Chrome and Safari => Same Behavior. I do now test directly with the FlashPlayer Application (out of the browser) => Same Behavior

Comment: Hi! just for the record, i've been able to test the streaming app on Mac Os 10.6.8(Snow Leopard), Unfortunatly i got the same problem as on Max Os Lion...